# iterating over dashmap stored in an arc

Tags: rust

```
let dashMap:DashMap<String,String>:DashMap::new();

// Then I put it into app_data of Actix to use it as a global variable, 
// which is an Arc.

// Then when I want to use it in iteration : 

for item:RefMulti<String,String> in dashMap.into_iter() {
   ...
}
```

I need to iterate the dashMap.
I'm not sure what to do with `item` as it is `RefMulti` type. I was expecting (k,v)

How would I access the key from iteration ?
Is there a nice way to access the `(key, value)` pairs even from `RefMulti` ?

[UPDATED WITH MRE]

```
//cargo.toml
actix-web = { version = "4.0.0-beta.6", features=["rustls"] }
dashmap = "4.0.2"
```

[[code]](https://gist.github.com/rust-play/2312d148dc93687e22c39ee8f33693c3)  is a gist, couldn't post it here. was getting formatting errors

Comment: Use `iter` rather than `into_iter`?

Comment: I'm getting the same kind of item

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.  Can you provide a [mre] and show the error?

Comment: you mean a playground ? Can I import Dashmap into it ? It's not enabled by default.

Comment: Just post the code.  I can run your code locally.

Comment: Ok question is updated....

Comment: RefMulti has a method [pair](https://docs.rs/dashmap/4.0.2/dashmap/mapref/multiple/struct.RefMulti.html#method.pair) that seems like it would give you a ref to key & value

Comment: Ah great, TY....